# Error while executing Except statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

`Marks(source table)` 
with coulmns:  
`class(number)`
`name(varchar)` 
`rollno(number)`

and 
`Result(target table)`
 
with column: 
`Grade(varchar)`

which can allow pass,fail,wrongdata values into it.

while comparing the data from both the two tables weather all the data from the source is migrated into target or not i am using the following case statement

```
   select 
      CASE  WHEN Class=4 THEN 'pass'            
            WHEN name='T' AND Class=4 THEN 'fail'
            WHEN rollno= 41 THEN 'pass'
            ELSE 'wrong data' END AS name 
   FROM class
   EXCEPT
   select grade 
   from result 
   where grade in('pass',fail','wrong data');
```

while i am trying to execute this query 'wrong data' is getting printed in the output without proper execution of the case statement.

I am trying to compare the values in the source table with the given when conditions with the target and if condition satisfies the output should be

```
       Name
```

simply column name should be displayed because  all the  conditions were satisfied in the source are present in the target

Comment: You need to rearrange the WHEN conditions in your CASE. If one row has class=4 it won't evaluate the other conditions anymore, because the first one is already satisfied.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You will never have the value 'fail', because Class=4 is true for all of that rows and they will get 'pass'.

Comment: Okay then why is the else part getting printed

Comment: WHEN name='T' AND Class=4 THEN 'fail' will never occur since all of them are caught by WHEN Class=4 THEN 'pass' - you maybe need to swap these 2 statements around.